# how to print integers without decimals or scientific notation c++

Tags: c++, format

I am trying to print the following ints using std::cout<<

> 256 6561 65536 390625 1679616 5764801 16777216 43046721 100000000

However, if I use this I get scientific notation:

```
#include <math.h>
for (int k = 2; k <=10; ++k)
    std::cout<< " " << pow(k, 8); //k to the power of 8
```

> 256 6561 65536 390625 1.67962e+06 5.7648e+06 1.67772e+07 4.30467e+07 1e+08

and if I use std::fixed, I get unwanted decimals:

```
for (int k = 2; k <=10; ++k)
    std::cout<< std::fixed << " " << pow(k, 8);
```

> 256.000000 6561.000000 65536.000000 390625.000000 1679616.000000 5764801.000000 16777216.000000 43046721.000000 100000000.000000

What do I need to do to print full-length integers?

Comment: Well the [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function *is* a floating point function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow` returns a floating point value, which is displayed in scientific notation when it becomes large or small. Cast to a sufficiently large integer so it will be displayed as an integer.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for (int k = 2; k <= 10; ++k)
        std::cout << " " << static_cast<int>(pow(k, 8));
}
```

Produces

> 256 6561 65536 390625 1679616 5764801 16777216 43046721 100000000

Comment: For sufficiently large numbers you'll probably overflow int's max value

Answer (score 2):

It would seem you are not fully utilizing std::cout functionality.

Streams have format flags that determine how values get sent out to the display.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // 2^64 is 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 without the ','s is 20 places.
    std::cout.precision(20);


    for (int k = 2; k <=10; ++k)
        std::cout<< " x = " << pow(k, 8); //k to the power of 8

    std::cout << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I actually found the answer to my question but I'll keep it because it might be useful to other people.

```
pow(a, b);
```

returns a "double floating point" as nwp suggested.
Therefore, std::fixed works correctly in avoiding scientific notation, and a simple:

```
static_cast<int>(pow(k, 8));
```

solves the problem

Comment: just a tip, in c++ avoid old style C casts. static_cast<int> is bettter choice

Comment: `(int)pow(k, 8);` introduces a different problem. `int` is not required to be able to represent values greater than 32767.

Comment: be wary of the maximum value int can hold